# How can I put the Observer Pattern to use?

Tags: javascript, observer-pattern

I'm just beginning to understand how the Observer Pattern works. But now I want to put it to use. I see lots of examples of the Observer Pattern, but most simply demonstrate the pattern and don't show it being implemented to complete a task.

I understand that an observer gets notified by a subject. But, how can I then get the observer to then do something as a result?

The code below is a common Observer Pattern program. I see that it executes a console.log (`console.log("Observer " + number + " is notified!");`) when an observer is notified. Is this where I could, instead, return other things: values, function calls, etc.?

I've seen visual examples with simple math that updates a calculation when an observer is notified (i.e., cost + tax = total). But I can't find an example that shows how the code is making this happening. 1. how/where is the new cost being returned and 2. so an observer (a function?) gets notified that the cost has changed; how/where does the function receive the updated cost?

I'm a novice and the pattern, itself, is a bit baffling on its own. I'd love to see a super basic example program.

```js
var Subject = function() {
  let observers = [];

  return {
    subscribeObserver: function(observer) {
      observers.push(observer);
    },
    unsubscribeObserver: function(observer) {
      var index = observers.indexOf(observer);
      if(index > -1) {
        observers.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
    notifyObserver: function(observer) {
      var index = observers.indexOf(observer);
      if(index > -1) {
        observers[index].notify(index);
      }
    },
    notifyAllObservers: function() {
      for(var i = 0; i < observers.length; i++){
        observers[i].notify(i);
      };
    }
  };
};

var Observer = function(number) {
  return {
    notify: function() {
      console.log("Observer " + number + " is notified!");
    }
  }
}

var subject = new Subject();

var observer1 = new Observer(1);
var observer2 = new Observer(2);

subject.subscribeObserver(observer1);
subject.subscribeObserver(observer2);

subject.notifyObserver(observer2);
subject.unsubscribeObserver(observer2);

subject.notifyAllObservers();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest form, an Observer is nothing but a function that is invoked by the Subject. More "complex" Observers would be objects with a "notify" or similar function, an error handler and maybe a "done" notification, depending on the Subject.

So here's a very basic example to demonstrate this:

```
var Subject = function() {
  let observers = [];

  return {
    subscribe: function(observer) {
      observers.push(observer);
    },
    unsubscribe: function(observer) {
      var index = observers.indexOf(observer);
      if(index > -1) {
        observers.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
    nextValue: function(value) {
      // call every registered observer
      for(var i = 0; i < observers.length; i++){
        observers[i](value);
      }
    }
  };
};

// now simply pass an observer function to the subject
const subject = new Subject();

subject.subscribe(value => {
  // do whatever you want with the value, call functions etc.
  console.log(value);
});

subject.nextValue('hello world!');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the RxJs library.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/

```js
const { Subject } = rxjs;

const subject$ = new Subject();

subject$.subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });

subject$.next('Hello');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.1/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The code below is a common Observer Pattern program. I see that it executes a console.log (console.log("Observer " + number + " is notified!");) when an observer is notified. Is this where I could, instead, return other things: values, function calls, etc.?

Yes when the subject calls notify it can pass data instead of an index or pass itself to the observer. In this way the observer can inspect Subject's state and do something with it. The method notifyObserver becomes:

```
notifyObserver: function(observer) { 
    var index = observers.indexOf(observer); 
    if(index > -1) { 
        observers[index].notify(this); 
    }
},
```

And the observer is something like:

```
var Observer = function(number) { 
    return { 
        notify: function(subject) { 
            // do something with subject 
           ... 
        } 
     } 
}
```